# How to increase the size of HTTP Post Request in Websphere

Tags: http, websphere

The HTTP specification doesn't impose a specific size limit for posts. They will usually be limited by either the web server or the programming technology used to process the form submission.

How i can increase this size for websphere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to rather change this via the Administrative Console.

In [V7](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/uwsv_plugin_props3.html) navigate to `Servers -> Server Types -> Web servers -> <servername> -> Plug-in properties -> Request routing`.

In [V6](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/uwsv_plugin_props3.html) you find this at `Servers -> Web Servers -> <servername> -> Plug-in properties -> Plug-in <serverclustername> Properties`.

There, change the `Maximum size of request content` parameter to `No Limit`. This sets the PostSizeLimit parameter.

The advantage is that this should also persist across a new plug-in generation, and is less error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

To change the size of post request you have to follow these steps :

1. Open the WebSphere plug-in configuration file (plugin-cfg.xml) in the
   WAS_HOME/config/cells directory with a text editor.
2. Locate the ServerCluster stanza with the following name:
   WebSphere_Portal__Cluster
3. Associated with this entry, find the parameter PostSizeLimit.
4. Change to a value in bytes (changing into a value to set a new limit or changing into "-1" to
   disables limit).
5. Save the changes and close the file.
6. Restart the application and portal servers.

Answer (score 0):

Websphere 8 users, follow these steps

1. Run `<WAS8-profiles-dir>\bin\GenPluginCfg.bat`
2. A file will be generated in `<WAS8-profiles-dir>\config\cells\plugin-cfg.xml`
3. Edit the `plugin-cfg.xml` file and change the `PostSizeLimit="30000000"`

Restart WAS8